# For php composer packages (published on packagist) what patch version comes after 1.0.9?

Tags: php, composer-php, versioning, semantic-versioning, packagist

What version should be published after `v1.0.9` so that composer update runs smoothly?

I am thinking the version should be bumped to either `v1.0.10` or `v1.0.901`.

Surprisingly, after almost 5 minutes of Google searches, I did not find a clear answer. This is for a package that is published on Packagist. It is not specified in https://semver.org/ (which is referenced from Packagist)

Comment: It's `1.0.10`. Where on earth are you getting `1.0.910` from? Actually, to be fair, 1.0.910 would work exactly as well, you're just skipping 900 version numbers for no reason.

Comment: In semantic versioning all numbers a incremental. Its just each of the numbers are incremented during different phases of a products a lifecycle. It would not be out the question to have a patch version number reach 1.0.10000, highly unlikely, but perfectly valid.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that composer did not decide to compare it as a decimal value (for example, 0.10 is smaller than 0.9).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 1.0.9. it is definitely 1.0.10.  I tested it, and composer update did work properly.

For more information on versioning: https://semver.org/

@[iainn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4680018/iainn) gets some credit. Unfortunately, I cannot accept a comment as the answer.